# Check database / server before executing query

Tags: sql, if-statement, mariadb

I am frequently testing certain areas on a development server and so running a pre-defined SQL statement to truncate the tables in question before testing again. It would only be a slip of a key to switch to the live server.
**I'm looking for an IF statement or similar to prevent that.**
Either to check the server name, database name, or even that a certain record in a different table exists before running the query.
Any help appreciated

Comment: How about using an account with no update and delete permissions for production environment? Do you need those permissions for that environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such cases I use stored procedures. I'd call them TestTruncateTables, etc.

Then instead of calling TRUNCATE TABLE you should CALL TestTruncateTables.

Just make sure that the procedures are not created on the live server. If by any chance you happen to run CALL TestTruncateTables on the live server you only get an error about non-existing proc.

Comment: That is an elegant solution. Thank you.